# PHP-функция по выводу ссылки на следующий файл в папке

Tags: php

Есть папка с php-файлами (страницами). Если в данный момент "открыт" один из этих файлов-страниц, как вывести на этой странице ссылку на следующий файл?
Есть функция next, в мануале приводится такой пример:

```
<?php
$transport = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'foot';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
?>
```

Однако:

Во-первых, заранее не известны названия файлов, из которых состоит массив. И, хотя сам массив можно "вытащить", например,

```
    $iterator = new FilesystemIterator(dirname(__FILE__).'/myFolder/');
    while($iterator->valid()) {
        echo $iterator->getBasename('.php').',';
        $iterator->next();
    }
```

но как его записать в переменную?

Во-вторых, как определить, что в данный момент открыт файл `foot`, чтобы с помощью next можно было дальше по массиву сослаться на `bike`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете найти все php файлы в директории при помощи функции `glob` и сохранить их в массив.
Далее по названию текущего файла находите его индекс в массиве файлов и увеличиваете на 1, чтобы получить название следующего файла.

```
$pathInfo = pathinfo(__FILE__);
$files = glob("*.php");
$currentIdx = array_search($pathInfo["basename"], $files);
$nextIdx = $currentIdx + 1;
if (isset($files[$nextIdx])) {
    echo "Следующий файл: {$files[$nextIdx]}";
} else {
    echo "Следующего файла нет";
}
```

Comment: Если оставить все как есть `$pathInfo = pathinfo(__FILE__);`, то выдает "Следующего файла нет". Если сделать так: `$page = $path.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; $pathInfo = pathinfo($page,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'.php';`, то вроде выдает "следующий файл", но что странно - из корневого каталога, а не из того, что нужно... а добавление в glob папки `$files = glob("myFolder/*.php");` выдает ошибку

Comment: @АндрейСахаров в glob необходимо передавать полный путь к директории. Например /home/user/site/myFolder/*.php

Comment: Но что еще интереснее: если `echo "Следующий файл: <a href='{$files[$nextIdx]}'>{$files[$nextIdx]}</a>";` то появляется ссылка на второй файл из корневого каталога (ну например, это config.php), но адрес ссылки http://mySite/myFolder/config.php. Что за бред?! Не могу понять эту машинную логику.

Comment: @АндрейСахаров Обращаясь к $files[$nextIdx] вы получаете только имя config.php, а путь у вас генерируется уже в html ссылке. Попробуйте например добавить / перед переменной и вы должны будете получить ссылку /config.php. Чтобы получить файлы из нужной директории передайте путь в glob как я написал выше.

Comment: да это уже ближе, получилась ссылка на файл (причем на сам файл, а не на страницу, но это уж я так вопрос задал). Но на открытый файл, а не на следующий

Comment: @АндрейСахаров вероятно ошибка с индексом. Распечатайте $files, посмотрите какие файлы под каким индексом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94201/discussion-between---and-qraxin).

Comment: спасибо за помощь